# Porting ShaderToy Chromakey example to P5.js

Tags: glsl, webgl, p5.js, fragment-shader, chromakey

I’m try to porting the shadertoy chromakey example to p5 with webcam as video source. After many time reading documentations of shaders, my code seems not working. I need some help.

[I followed this guide to port the code for the p5](https://itp-xstory.github.io/p5js-shaders/#/./docs/examples/shadertoy)

Fragment shader code:

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif

uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;

mat4 RGBtoYUV = mat4(0.257,  0.439, -0.148, 0.0,
                     0.504, -0.368, -0.291, 0.0,
                     0.098, -0.071,  0.439, 0.0,
                     0.0625, 0.500,  0.500, 1.0 );


vec4 chromaKey = vec4(0.05, 0.63, 0.14, 1);

vec2 maskRange = vec2(0.005, 0.26);


float colorclose(vec3 yuv, vec3 keyYuv, vec2 tol)
{
    float tmp = sqrt(pow(keyYuv.g - yuv.g, 2.0) + pow(keyYuv.b - yuv.b, 2.0));
    if (tmp < tol.x)
      return 0.0;
    else if (tmp < tol.y)
      return (tmp - tol.x)/(tol.y - tol.x);
    else
      return 1.0;
}


void main()
{
    vec2 fragPos =  gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec4 texColor0 = texture(text0, fragPos);
    vec4 texColor1 = texture(text1, fragPos);

    vec4 keyYUV =  RGBtoYUV * chromaKey;
    vec4 yuv = RGBtoYUV * texColor0;

    float mask = 1.0 - colorclose(yuv.rgb, keyYUV.rgb, maskRange);
    gl_FragColor = max(texColor0 - mask * chromaKey, 0.0) + texColor1 * mask;
}
```

P5 sketch code:

```
let theShader;
let cam;

let img;

function preload(){

  theShader = loadShader('webcam.vert', 'webcam.frag');

  img = loadImage('http://www.quadrochave.com/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/nodulo_bannersite_ptodu%C3%A7%C3%A3o2-mpe2nvmu8s8o2uqcd7b2oh3mnuv9up05ubby33shz4.png');
}

function setup() {
  pixelDensity(1);

  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  noStroke();

  cam = createCapture(VIDEO);
  cam.size(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  cam.hide();
}

function draw() {
  // shader() sets the active shader with our shader
  shader(theShader);

  // passing cam as a texture
  theShader.setUniform('tex0', cam);
  theShader.setUniform('tex1', img);

  // rect gives us some geometry on the screen
  theShader.rect(0,0,width,height);

}
```

[Test on Glitch](https://glitch.com/~chromakey-test)

[Shadertoy chromakey original fragment shader](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/MlVXWD)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mayor issue is, that you didn't specify and set the uniform variable `iResolution`. But there are some more issues in the shader code (`tex0` and `tex1` rather than `text0` and `text1`).

Fragment shader:

```c
precision mediump float;

uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform vec2 iResolution;

mat4 RGBtoYUV = mat4(0.257,  0.439, -0.148, 0.0,
                        0.504, -0.368, -0.291, 0.0,
                        0.098, -0.071,  0.439, 0.0,
                        0.0625, 0.500,  0.500, 1.0 );


vec4 chromaKey = vec4(0.05, 0.63, 0.14, 1);

vec2 maskRange = vec2(0.005, 0.26);

float colorclose(vec3 yuv, vec3 keyYuv, vec2 tol)
{
    float tmp = sqrt(pow(keyYuv.g - yuv.g, 2.0) + pow(keyYuv.b - yuv.b, 2.0));
    if (tmp < tol.x)
        return 0.0;
    else if (tmp < tol.y)
        return (tmp - tol.x)/(tol.y - tol.x);
    else
        return 1.0;
}

void main()
{
    vec2 fragPos =  gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;
    vec4 texColor0 = texture2D(tex0, fragPos);
    vec4 texColor1 = texture2D(tex1, fragPos);

    vec4 keyYUV =  RGBtoYUV * chromaKey;
    vec4 yuv = RGBtoYUV * texColor0;

    float mask = 1.0 - colorclose(yuv.rgb, keyYUV.rgb, maskRange);
    gl_FragColor = max(texColor0 - mask * chromaKey, 0.0) + texColor1 * mask;
}
```

Script:

```js
let theShader;
let cam;
let img;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);

    theShader = loadShader('webcam.vert', 'webcam.frag');
    img = loadImage('http://www.quadrochave.com/wp-content/uploads/elementor/thumbs/nodulo_bannersite_ptodu%C3%A7%C3%A3o2-mpe2nvmu8s8o2uqcd7b2oh3mnuv9up05ubby33shz4.png');

    pixelDensity(1);
    noStroke();

    cam = createCapture(VIDEO);
    cam.size(windowWidth, windowHeight);

    cam.hide();
}

function draw() {
    // shader() sets the active shader with our shader
    shader(theShader);

    // passing cam as a texture
    theShader.setUniform('tex0', cam);
    theShader.setUniform('tex1', img);
    theShader.setUniform('iResolution', [width, height]);

    // rect gives us some geometry on the screen
    rect(0,0,width,height);
}
```

---

If the vertex shader provides the texture the coordinate:

```c
// our vertex data
attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

// lets get texcoords just for fun! 
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
    // copy the texcoords
    vTexCoord = aTexCoord;

    // copy the position data into a vec4, using 1.0 as the w component
    vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
    positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

    // send the vertex information on to the fragment shader
    gl_Position = positionVec4;
}
```

then you can use this coordinate instead of `gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy`:

```c
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

// [...]

void main() {
    vec2 fragPos = vTexCoord.xy;

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: Thanks !

I',m using a vertex shader template , but the fragment shader is not using vTexCoord. May you see this code ?

Comment: Thanks very much ! I still triying understanding the errors with using vTexCoord while compiling the fragment shader:
 'vTexCoord' : undeclared identifier
ERROR: 0:55: 'xy' :  field selection requires structure or vector on left hand side
ERROR: 0:55: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:55: '=' : cannot convert from 'const highp float' to 'mediump 2-component vector of float'
ERROR: 0:56: 'texture' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:56: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:56: '=' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'mediump 4-component vector of float'

Comment: Yes. Here the code:

attribute vec3 aPosition;
attribute vec2 aTexCoord;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

void main() {
  vTexCoord = aTexCoord;
  vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
  positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

  gl_Position = positionVec4;
}

Comment: Sorry You say fragment shader ! No, i had forgotten to declare in this file. Here the declarations now:
uniform sampler2D tex0;
uniform sampler2D tex1;
uniform vec2 iResolution;

varying vec2 vTexCoord;

Comment: [rabbid76][1] thanks for your help and patience. I had changed the "texture2D" method to "texture" for testing and had forgotten to go back. It's finally work !!